# Android, Handler's error

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

This is a bit weird, but I have no idea where the problem is.

In my onCreate() I have this code:

```
GameRunningNotesTimer().start();
```

and then out of onCreate I have this code:

```
Thread GameRunningNotesTimer = new Thread(new Runnable() { 

    public void run() {

        int sleepingTime;
        try {
            if (r_settings.getGameOver() == 0) {

                sleepingTime = 1000 - (r_settings.getInternalLevel() * 100);

                if (r_settings.getInternalLevel() == 0) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); 
                } else {
                            if (sleepingTime <= 399) 
                            {
                                sleepingTime = 350;
                            }
                            Thread.sleep(sleepingTime);
                        }
                    if (r_settings.getGameOver() == 1){ gameOver(); }

                myHandler2.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            } // End of if (r_settings.getGameOver()
        } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("MUSIC!!!!!", "Error in activity", e); }
    }// End of run
}); // End of GameRunningNotesTimer()




final Handler myHandler2 = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        //text2.setText(""+item[0]);
        int z = 1;

        if (r_settings.getGameStarted() == true)
        {
            changeNoteFromTimer(); 
        } else {
            startingCountdown(z);
        } 

    } // end of handleMessage()

};
```

but this **`GameRunningNotesTimer`**().start(); is underlined in red (in Eclipse) and when I mouseover it it says: `The method GameRunningNotesTimer() is undefined for the type GameScr`

What am I doing wrong? another thread/handler in the same class is not giving me this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `GameRunningNotesTimer.start();` **not** `GameRunningNotesTimer().start();`

Comment: Gah! So stupid... and thats why even a search for the text didnt give me any errors... Thanks nate!

Comment: Just take a chill pill buddy, it happens sometimes don't worry. :)